# Reading an address relative to the base address from a process with ReadProcessMemory

Tags: c++, winapi

A few years ago, I did some memory reading stuff, mostly for fun. The standard was 32 bit back then.

I've modified my existing code to run on x64 systems, but cannot seem to read an address relative to the process base address. My day job doesn't really involve lower level programming so I am very rusty.

In short: I want to read a memory address, relative to the base address of a process so I can do something useful.

In cheat engine, I can use:

Wow-64.exe + 0x173D390

To read my address no problem.

When trying to emulate this, I can determine (I think successfully) the process base address. However, when I try to read the "address" from the pointer, I am always receiving 0xCCCCCCCC. Obviously something is not right, but I'm struggling to find how to debug this further...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

using namespace std;

UINT_PTR GetProcessBaseAddress(DWORD processID, HANDLE *processHandle);

int main()
{
    HWND WindowHandle = FindWindow(nullptr, L"World of Warcraft");
    DWORD PID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(WindowHandle, &PID);
    HANDLE      processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);
    if (processHandle == 0) {
        cout << "Could not open process";
        return 1;
    }

    UINT_PTR BaseAddress = GetProcessBaseAddress(PID, &processHandle);
    UINT_PTR PlayerBaseAddress = (BaseAddress + 0x173D390);

    UINT_PTR PlayerBase;

    ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, (void *)PlayerBaseAddress, &PlayerBase, sizeof(PlayerBase, 0));


    cout << "Process base: " << hex << BaseAddress << ", Player Base Address: " << hex << PlayerBaseAddress << ", Actual address: " << hex << PlayerBase << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


UINT_PTR GetProcessBaseAddress(DWORD processID, HANDLE *processHandle)
{
    DWORD_PTR   baseAddress = 0;

    HMODULE     *moduleArray;
    LPBYTE      moduleArrayBytes;
    DWORD       bytesRequired;

    if (*processHandle)
    {
        if (EnumProcessModulesEx(*processHandle, NULL, 0, &bytesRequired, 0x02))
        {
            if (bytesRequired)
            {
                moduleArrayBytes = (LPBYTE)LocalAlloc(LPTR, bytesRequired);

                if (moduleArrayBytes)
                {
                    unsigned int moduleCount;

                    moduleCount = bytesRequired / sizeof(HMODULE);
                    moduleArray = (HMODULE *)moduleArrayBytes;

                    if (EnumProcessModulesEx(*processHandle, moduleArray, bytesRequired, &bytesRequired, 0x02))
                    {
                        baseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)moduleArray[0];
                    }

                    LocalFree(moduleArrayBytes);
                }
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(*processHandle);
    }

    return baseAddress;
}
```

**Edit**
Actual output of console

```
Process base: 7ff7395d0000, Player Base Address: 7ff73ad0d390, Actual address: cccccccccccccccc
```

Comment: So, the target process is a 64-bit process?  Did you remember to build your application as 64-bit too?

Comment: Should have mentioned, Yes target process is 64-bit and I'm building as 64-bit too

Comment: The first thing to do is to check whether ReadProcessMemory() succeeded, and if not, what the error code was.

Comment: You have a misplaced bracket. `sizeof(PlayerBase, 0)`.

Comment: you call `CloseHandle(*processHandle);` in `GetProcessBaseAddress` so you call `ReadProcessMemory() ` with already closed handle

Comment: Thank you kind sir! This, combined with ensuring I ran it _outside_ of the debugger fixed the issue.

Comment: Also, using `XXX_PTR` data types when reading values from other processes is not a good idea unless you can ensure your app and the target app are using the same bitness. The size of `XXX_PTR` data types are dependent on compiler settings. So, if you know you are reading an N-bit value, use an N-bit data type to read it, regardless of how your app is configured to be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to RbMm, I had accidentally left a call to CloseHandle() inside GetProcessBaseAddress. Remove this and placing it inside main() resolved the issue.

The program only seems to execute correctly when in "Release" mode in VS also.

---

if you want only get base address of `EXE` you not need enum *ALL* process modules. `EXE` is always first module in process - so enough query only one:

```
ULONG GetProcessBaseAddress(HANDLE hProcess, HMODULE* phmod)
{
    ULONG cb;
    return EnumProcessModulesEx(hProcess, phmod, sizeof(HMODULE), &cb, LIST_MODULES_DEFAULT) ? 0 : GetLastError();
}
```

and use like this

```
        union {
            HMODULE hmod;
            ULONG_PTR BaseAddress;
        };
        ULONG err = GetProcessBaseAddress(h, &hmod);
        if (!err)
        {
            DbgPrint("%p\n", BaseAddress + 0x173D390 );
        }
```